# Increase output buffer from Springboot Websocket Java Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, sockjs

I'm using the library "org.springframework.web.socket" to connect to a web socket server. It works fine if the message is small, but if the message is bigger than a few kB, the connection closes with this message:

**"The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages"**

StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.ConnectionLostException: Connection closed
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.afterConnectionClosed(DefaultStompSession.java:526)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketStompClient.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.afterConnectionClosed(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.AbstractClientSockJsSession.afterTransportClosed(AbstractClientSockJsSession.java:350)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.client.WebSocketTransport$ClientSockJsWebSocketHandler.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketTransport.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:145)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.fireEndpointOnClose(WsSession.java:556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:534)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataControl(WsFrameBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:296)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.processSocketRead(WsFrameClient.java:95)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.resumeProcessing(WsFrameClient.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient.access$500(WsFrameClient.java:31)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.doResumeProcessing(WsFrameClient.java:189)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:163)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameClient$WsFrameClientCompletionHandler.completed(WsFrameClient.java:148)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Client code:

```
private final int MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.setDefaultMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
container.setDefaultMaxTextMessageBufferSize(MAX_TEXT_MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);

List<Transport> transports = new ArrayList<>();
transports.add(new WebSocketTransport(new StandardWebSocketClient(container)));
SockJsClient sockJsClient = new SockJsClient(transports);

stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(sockJsClient);
stompClient.setInboundMessageSizeLimit(512 * 1024);
stompClient.setMessageConverter(new MappingJackson2MessageConverter());

stompSession = stompClient.connect(websocketsEndPoint, this).get();
```

On the server side, I'm using a spring boot websocket server with a RabbitMQ broker.

Server Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // Broker config...    
    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setMessageSizeLimit(500 * 1024);
        registration.setSendBufferSizeLimit(1024 * 1024);
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(20000);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS()
                .setStreamBytesLimit(1024 * 1024)
                .setHttpMessageCacheSize(1000)
                .setDisconnectDelay(3000);
        registry.addEndpoint("/endpoint").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

I have tried all the solutions of other threads, but it doesn't work for me.
Anyone knows how can I solve this problem?